# How to concat two varchars in jdbc/derby?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, netbeans, derby

I want to run this code in JDBC/Derby but I got the below error. How can I handle it in JDBC?

Code:

```
   SELECT ID,Namee+ " " + Family AS NameS
   FROM Students
```

Errorr:

```
The '+' operator with a left operand type of 'VARCHAR' and a right operand type of 'VARCHAR' is not supported.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Derby uses the `||` operator to concat strings (like Oracle):

```
SELECT ID, Namee || " " || Family AS NameS
FROM Students
```

Comment: Like the SQL standard ;)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I wasn't aware that was part of the SQL standard. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: SQL:2011 Foundation, section 5.2 (_`<token>` and `<separator>`_)

Answer (score 0):

Answer )

SELECT ID,Namee || ' ' || Family AS NameS
FROM Students

Using " " instead of ' ' gave the below error.

Column ' ' is either not in any table in the FROM list or appears within a join specification and is outside the scope of the join specification or appears in a HAVING clause and is not in the GROUP BY list. If this is a CREATE or ALTER statement then, ' ' is not a column in the target table.